# Change special chars in string

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# and in code from appsettings.json I take strings and convert them if special chars exists. this is my code

```
int? a = applicationRequestViewModel.GetApplicantIndex();
int? g = applicationRequestViewModel.GetGurantorIndex();

foreach (var keys in _options.Value.RegisterParamKeys)
{
    string value = keys.Split(";")[0];
    string name = keys.Split(";")[1];
    string key = value.Split(":")[typeOfApplicant];
    key = Regex.Replace(key, @"[^\[a\]]", "[" + a + "]");
    key = Regex.Replace(key, @"[^\[g\]]", "[" + g + "]");
    var registrationProperty = new RegistrationProperty() { };
    registrationProperty.Name = name;
    registrationProperty.Value = (string)rss.SelectToken(key);
    listOfRegistrationProperty.Add(registrationProperty);
}
```

from appsettings.json I took below strings

```
"RegisterBatchParams": [
    "applicationInfo.applicationNumber:applicationInfo.applicationNumber:applicationInfo.applicationNumber:applicationInfo.applicationNumber;applicationNumber",
    "applicationInfo.applicantType:applicationInfo.applicantType:applicationInfo.applicantType:applicationInfo.applicantType;applicantType",
    "applicationInfo.customerSegment:applicationInfo.customerSegment:applicationInfo.customerSegment:applicationInfo.customerSegment;customerSegment",
    "applicationInfo.applicationStatusLocalText:applicationInfo.applicationStatusLocalText:applicationInfo.applicationStatusLocalText:applicationInfo.applicationStatusLocalText;applicationStatus",
    "applicationRequestViewModel.applicants[a].businessPartner.person.firstName:applicationRequestViewModel.applicants[a].businessPartner.person.firstName:applicationRequestViewModel.applicants[a].businessPartner.person.firstName:applicationRequestViewModel.applicants[a].businessPartner.person.firstName;customerName"
  ],
```

for the last string I want to change `"applicants[a]"` to with index number but it doesn't convert as expected how can I convert correctly?

As expected result

```
applicationRequestViewModel.applicants[0].businessPartner.person.firstName
```

but given result

```
a[0][0][0][0][0]a[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]a[0][0][0][0][0]a[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: You are asking it to replace _anything but the characters_ `[`, `a`, and `]` with `[0]`. Why do you need regex? Just do a string-replace for `"[a]"` with `"[" + a + "]"`

Comment: Is there a reason to use regex instead of string.replace?

Comment: but  There can be more than one for replacing. So replace change all or only one ?

Comment: @pc_coder string.Replace changes all occurences, not just the first. Are you comming from a JS background?

Comment: @Magnetron yes.  then thanks :)

Comment: @pc_coder that should be easy enough to find out if you try it. I find https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to be pretty helpful to test quick snippets

Comment: @pc_coder yeah, when I move from C# to JS I was very confused too as why it was just replacing the first ocurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@"[^\[a\]]"` use `@"\[a\]"`.

But you don't even need regex for this. Simple `string.Replace` will do the job just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can try this regex and replace only char inside of parentheses.

```
[a](?=[]])
```